# What Software Does Wikibooks Use?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I know they use MediaWiki but do they use any specific extensions that allow them to have hierarchies of pages/etc?

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special:Version

Shows you all the extensions that they are using